# My Random Password Generator throws an error. How do I fix this?

Tags: c, password-generator

I wrote a Random Password Generator in C. But my code throws an error. What is the problem? How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{   
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    int k_sayi,i;
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    char kucuk_harf[26]="abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz";
    char buyuk_harf[26]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";
    char sayilar[11]="1234567890";
    char ozel_karakter[13]="!'^+%&/=?_*";
    char *pass;

    printf("Parola kac karakterli olsun?: ");
    scanf("%d",&k_sayi);

    pass=(char *)malloc(k_sayi*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf);
    }
    pass[i]='\0';
    printf("%s",pass);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is that error

Comment: Don't forget to `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i]=rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf);
    }
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<k_sayi-1;i++){
        pass[i]=rand()%(sizeof kucuk_harf);
    }
```

it should work.

If you have an array of size `n`, you can iterate through it from `0` to `n-1`.
You already do that in the for loop, but then want to access `pass[i]`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: @JL2210 let's say `k_sayi` is 10. then the for loop goes from 0 to 9. and sets `i` to 10 after the last run through the loop.
After that he says `pass[i]='\0';` and `i` is `10`, so out of bounds

Comment: Yes, but instead he should `malloc(k_sayi+1);`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this, otherwise there will be an out-of-bounds write and read:

```
pass = malloc(k_sayi+1);
```

You also need to do this to get readable ASCII characters:

```
pass[i] = kucuk_harf[rand() % strlen(kucuk_harf)];
```

Also, remove both of your `srand` calls and place one after `char *pass;` for your code to be ANSI-compliant.

This is a working version of the code that has unused variables commented out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int k_sayi,i;
    char kucuk_harf[]="abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz";
/*    char buyuk_harf[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ"; */
/*    char sayilar[]="1234567890"; */
/*    char ozel_karakter[]="!'^+%&/=?_*"; */
    char *pass;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Parola kac karakterli olsun?: ");
    scanf("%d", &k_sayi);

    pass = malloc(k_sayi+1);

    for(i=0;i<k_sayi;i++){
        pass[i] = kucuk_harf[rand() % (sizeof(kucuk_harf) - 1)];
    }

    pass[i]='\0';
    puts(pass);

    /* make sure to free */
    free(pass);

    return 0;
}
```